# How to store word vectors embeddings?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, word2vec, opennlp, word-embedding

I'm very new to `NLP` and `Deep Learning` field and want to understand that after vectorization of a whole corpus using `Word2Vec`, Do I need to store the word vector values locally?
If yes I want to make a chatbot for `android.` Can anyone please guide me for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

word2vec embeddings can be saved:

- in first layers of your deep model. It's rare approach, because in this case you can't use this word2vec for other tasks.
- as independent file on disk. It's more viable apporach for most use cases.

I'd suggest to use gensim framework for training of word2vec. Here you can learn more how to train word2vec and save them to disk: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Particularly, saving is performed via:

```
model = Word2Vec(common_texts, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
model.save("word2vec.model")
```

Training of chatbot is much more difficult problem. I can try to suggest you a possible workflow, but you should to clarify what type of chatbot do you have in mind? E.g. should it answer on any question (open domain)? Should it generate answers or it will have predefined answers only?

Comment: Basically like an assistant. if input is " wake me up after 3 hours" action should be set alarm current time+3 hours. After setting alarm it should generate a humanly text like "As you wish,i'll wake you after 3 hrs" or something like this.

Comment: I think in this case you have to 
1) create neural network which takes on input a sequence with request and predicts class of this request.
Here is a good tutorial: https://ahmedbesbes.com/sentiment-analysis-on-twitter-using-word2vec-and-keras.html

2) create an extra NER (Named Entity Recognition) model, which will extract parameters of input request. In your example "3"  is such argument (time of alarm). You can train it yourself, but I'd suggest to learn spacy.

Comment: Thank you. But how can i store word vector as independent file in android

Comment: In my answer you can see the command which saves a word2vec model to disk. You can use it from android. The only problem I see: word2vec is quite big model (can reach more the 10 GB). I think you should perform all logic on the server.